# How to split an image with a grid and preserve transparency bounding box

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, bounding-box

I have some png images that I want to split it into parts, like by grid or size.

But each part should have the same bounding box (transparency) as original image.

**Example:**

Splitting image into 2 parts.

**Original:** 200 × 89

[image]

**Output:**

---

part_1.png, 200 × 89

[image]

---

part_2.png, 200 × 89

[image]

Can ImageMagick do this? Or any other app or method.

My actual goal is to split into 100+ slices images.

---

**EDIT:**

Another goal to have an **indents** for each slice. Say `indent = 10px`.

**Example:**

**Input:** 200 x 100

[image]

---

**Output:**

---

part_1.png, 200 x 100

[image]

---

part_2.png, 200 x 100

[image]

And just as example, to visually compare input and output: combined output images in Photoshop as layer added one onto another
200 x 100 :

[image]

Also this is showing input image added onto combined(so it's better to see what was cropped and how):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can split an image into many parts with the -crop command. For your example above with two parts, you can do that with the following commands. ImageMagick will append -0, -1 ... to the output file names.

ImageMagick 6:

```
dim=`convert image.png -format "%wx%h" info:`
convert \( -size $dim xc:none \) null: \( image.png -crop 50x100% \) -layers composite result.png
```

ImageMagick 7:

```
magick \( image.png -set option:dim "%wx%h" -crop 50x100% \) null: \( -size "%[dim]" xc:none \) -reverse -layers composite result.png
```

The results are:

[image]

[image]

See

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_percent
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_quad
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_equal

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#layers

Note that -crop keeps the virtual canvas information if you do not add +repage afterwards. So to put the individual images back into their original placement, you have to composite them onto a transparent background the size of the input. That is done in one command using -layers composite using the null: separator.

Comment: Thank you! Works really well. One more thing: is it possible to improve command to do following: find all `.png` files in directory and crop it like currently, but give name like input was: image_1.png and output filenames will be image_1_1.png, image_1_2.png .. and so on.

Comment: And one more thing :) - can I have indents in output images? From all sides, so if `indent = 10` images finally should be like this: http://i.piccy.info/i9/e8c296de097d5fbd155030ba52120b70/1528748434/318/1216561/TC5OC.png  - please notice `-10` pixes cut from each sides.

Comment: I am not sure what indents you want? Can you explain further? The crop command allows offsets, but then you cannot split into multiple parts. Please make a drawing showing how you want an indent or offset. Is it for one crop or for all crops?

Comment: I can say that each image will be trimmed like shown: http://i.piccy.info/i9/b8533c21cf6761d2432042cf63931997/1528749085/3404/1216561/TC5OC.png  and so as result it will be looks like this: http://i.piccy.info/i9/e8c296de097d5fbd155030ba52120b70/1528748434/318/1216561/TC5OC.png  but png size will remains the same. Thats I'm calling `indent`. If this not clear, I can provide more detailed example.

Comment: Another example: if [this image](http://i.piccy.info/i9/936805cfaf0ebe48bb2c34132857db76/1528749668/261/1216561/input.png) is `input.png`, so just all filled red and I'm cropping it into `2` parts with `indent = 10px` and then I just adding that parts as layers in Photoshop one onto another I [will get this](http://i.piccy.info/i9/7d1cd8c9e0bfbcbf20167087ba5db2dc/1528749840/377/1216561/output_combined.png) So, probably it's for all crops.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to add transparent areas between parts of a crop in ImageMagick. Crop the image into pieces, chop off the parts you want to remove, then pipe to montage to add the spacing back.

Input:

[image]

Here I make this into a 4x4 grid of images with 10 pixel spacing:

```
convert lena.png -crop 25%x25% +repage -gravity east -chop 10x0 -gravity south -chop 0x10 +repage miff:- | montage - -background none -tile 4x4 -geometry +5+5 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: When I run this I get: `Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag` But anyway I have `result.png` file. [Input image used](http://i.piccy.info/i9/e6689df57a7b9813ff9ea9e784adc141/1528791599/855/1216561/input.png) and [result image](http://i.piccy.info/i9/04dc64ad5ac1d078454ed8e1ee43bd95/1528791633/545/1216561/result.png). So the problems: 1) it's like starts to crop from left top. 2) it's one image on output, please check my comments from other your answer. Overall this is looks like almost what I need.

Comment: I've edited question, I hope I'm clear now, sorry for my english, thats the main problem I think..

Answer (score 1):

To answer your new question, you can do that with a script loop. On a Unix-like platform, assuming your images do not have spaces, you can do the following:

```
cd path/to/current_folder
list=`ls *.png`
for img in $list; do
name=`convert $img -format "%t" info:`
dim=`convert $img -format "%wx%h" info:`
convert \( -size $dim xc:none \) null: \( $img -crop 50x100% \) -layers composite -scene 1 path/to/new_folder/${name}_%d.png
done
```

If you want leading 0s in the output, say 3, use path/to/new_folder/${name}_%03d.png.

Note that to start with 1 rather than 0, I have added -scene 1.

Sorry, I do not know how to script for Windows.

Please always provide your ImageMagick version and platform.

Comment: I'm on macOS. Just installed `ImageMagick` today: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx so should be the latest(however I've used first script, because `-bash: magick: command not found` error for 2nd. ). So do I need to create a sh file to run this?

Comment: What is your version of ImageMagick? Try either `convert -version` or `magick -version`. convert for IM 6 and magick for IM 7. You do not need to add bash if you are copying and pasting into a terminal window. If you save as script, then you must add bash before the script name.

Comment: `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.9-40 Q16`

Comment: Magick is for IM 7. You are using IM 6, so you need to use the convert format of the commands.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, the best way to put transparent areas into your image is with a binary mask that is put into the alpha channel of your image.

[image]

```
convert input.png \( -size 200x89 xc:white -size 10x89 xc:black -gravity center -composite \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

You can add as many blank areas as you want by adding more white areas to the mask or by tiling out one region of black and one region of white to create the mask with regular spacing of black and white.

Comment: Thats my fault, I've described not clearly. So, what I should add: in any cases(just crop, or crop with insets) on output I expect multiple images, so result-0.png, result-1.png and so on. I showed example of like these images combined in Photoshop, just to show that finally it's has insets compare to original image. Another words - with just simple crop from you 1-st answer, if you combine outputs into 1 image you will get exactly the same look as input.png. But if `insets` used you will get same as you showed - `lena.png`. But anyways on it's  multiple images and same size.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to add this ImageMagick 6 example which splits the input image into 4 pieces, 25% of the original width and 100% of its height, then creates a transparent canvas for each piece the same dimensions of the input image, and locates the pieces at their original offsets on those canvases.

```
convert input.png -set option:distort:viewport %[w]x%[h] -crop 25x100% \
   -virtual-pixel none -distort affine "0,0 %[fx:s.page.x],%[fx:s.page.y]" out%03d.png
```

The output file names will be numbered starting from zero like "out000.png", etc.

Original message...

Here's a simple command using ImageMagick 7 that can crop an image into any number of pieces, and output all the pieces at their original offsets on transparent backgrounds of the original input dimensions...

```
magick input.png -crop 100x1@ -background none \
   -extent "%[fx:s.page.width]x%[fx:s.page.height]-%[fx:s.page.x]-%[fx:s.page.y]" out%03d.png
```

That "-crop 100x1@" tells it to split the image into a grid 100 pieces wide by 1 piece high. You could just as well specify the crop sizes as percents or numbers of pixels.

Edited again to add:

This following command will split the input image into the individual pieces specified with the "-crop" operator, then shave 5 pixels from every side of each piece, then apply a 5 pixel transparent border to every side of each piece. It will still remember the original locations of the pieces within the input canvas, so the "-distort affine ..." can extend the canvases and place the pieces where they were in the input image.

```
convert input.png -set option:distort:viewport %[w]x%[h] \
   -bordercolor none -background none -virtual-pixel none \
   -crop 25x100% -shave 5x5 -border 5x5 \
   -distort affine "0,0 %[fx:s.page.x],%[fx:s.page.y]" out%03d.png
```

To use this command with IM7 you need to change "convert" to "magick".

Comment: Thanks. Can I add an insets like also, like in previous question comments, thats something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y8gi.png but separated images.

Comment: If I understand your question you should be able to add "-shave NxN -border NxN" right after the crop, with N being the width of the space you want around the image pieces. Make sure you set "-bordercolor none -background none" before the shave and border operation so the space around the pieces will be transparent.

Comment: can you please share all this complete command? I've just installed `ImageMagick` yesterday, so I'm just learning it.. Could you please edit your answer also, if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Given the changes of requirements provided by Kamikaze, here is one way to achieve the split with indent in ImageMagick, assuming I understand correctly.

[image]

```
dim=`convert image.png -format "%wx%h" info:`
convert \( -size $dim xc:none \) null: \( image.png -crop 50x100% -shave 5x5 \) -geometry +5+5 -layers composite result.png
```

[image]

[image]

To check, I flatten over a blue background:

```
convert result-0.png result-1.png -background blue -flatten result.png
```

[image]