# ImageMagick: detect fully transparent blank images

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick 6 for slicing my images into parts.
[How to split an image with a grid and preserve transparency bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803478/how-to-split-an-image-with-a-grid-and-preserve-transparency-bounding-box)

```
dim=`convert image.png -format "%wx%h" info:`
convert \( -size $dim xc:none \) null: \( image.png -crop 10x10% \) -layers composite result.png
```

All works perfect, but if I use input image like this:

[image]

On output I'm getting some **fully transparent empty** images, because from input image - there is nothing at the corners of it.

Yes, that how it should work, however I'm looking how to avoid that.

Or remove that blank images from disk, because I don't need them.

If there is no normal way to do this?

I'm thinking about workaround also, like detect fully empty images and modify them(fill with color or any other, no matter), so after that I can sort output files in Finder just by modified date and remove them manually.

p.s. I have images like that circle 2000 x 2000px size and slice at 5%, imagine number of empty images on output.. remove that manually is more than a pain.

Comment: @fmw42 could you please take a look? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give me a better understanding of what you expect for the output? Can you split it manually to show me the resulting parts?

Comment: I used code from this question for given image. Here folder with that image and output files: [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rbe3xgmenhpqv99/AADsDxiSlRXJYAMDk-sc5lyUa?dl=1](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rbe3xgmenhpqv99/AADsDxiSlRXJYAMDk-sc5lyUa?dl=1) You can see that fully blank images.

Comment: As far a I know, there are no options in Imagemagick -crop to ignore fully transparent tiles. You will have to test each tile to see if it is fully transparent and then discard it. You can tell if a tile is fully transparent if the result of this command is gray(0): `convert result-0.png -background black -alpha background -alpha extract -scale 1x1! -format "%[pixel:u.p]" info:`

Comment: @fmw42, it's cool that it could be detected, but as I said, I have at least 2000 such sprites, so can Imagemagick do this detect empty and fill it with black? That would really helped me.

Comment: If you detect the images that are fully transparent, then all you need do is turn the alpha channel off and the result will be black. `convert transparent.png -alpha off black.png`

Comment: @fmw42 could you please post an answer? I'm not really familiar with Imagemagick (( to use that both code for one purpose. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a script loop as follows in Unix Imagemagick 6. I have put your input image in a directory called test on my desktop. I am not sure why you used your commands above, but it can cropped directly without the layers composite. I save all the cropped images to layers of a temporary miff file, which I delete at the end. The basic idea is to test each cropped image to see if its alpha channel is pure black (or nearly pure black to avoid tiny very transparent single pixels).

1) If it is black within some small threshold, then remove the alpha channel from the miff layer saving it as black numbered output image. Otherwise, just save the layer as a numbered output image.

```
cd
cd desktop/test
convert image.png -background black -alpha background -crop 10x10% image.miff
num=`convert image.miff -format "%n\n" info: | head -n 1`
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
trans_test=`convert image.miff[$i] -alpha extract -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:mean<=0.0001?0:1]" info:`
echo "i=$i test=$trans_test"
if [ $trans_test -eq 0 ]; then
convert image.miff[$i] -alpha off result-$i.png
else
convert image.miff[$i] result-$i.png
fi
done
rm -f image.miff
cd
```

2) If the alpha channel is nearly black, skip that layer

```
cd
cd desktop/test
convert image.png -background black -alpha background -crop 10x10% image.miff
num=`convert image.miff -format "%n\n" info: | head -n 1`
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
trans_test=`convert image.miff[$i] -alpha extract -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:mean<=0.0001?0:1]" info:`
echo "i=$i test=$trans_test"
if [ $trans_test -eq 1 ]; then
convert image.miff[$i] result-$i.png
fi
done
rm -f image.miff
cd
```

3) If the alpha channel is black skip it, but number the results sequentially for only the ones kept.

```
cd
cd desktop/test
j=0
convert image.png -background black -alpha background -crop 10x10% image.miff
num=`convert image.miff -format "%n\n" info: | head -n 1`
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
trans_test=`convert image.miff[$i] -alpha extract -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:mean<=0.0001?0:1]" info:`
echo "i=$i test=$trans_test"
if [ $trans_test -eq 1 ]; then
convert image.miff[$i] result-$j.png
j=$((j+1))
fi
done
rm -f image.miff
cd
```

4) If the alpha channel is black skip it, but number the results sequentially for only the ones kept with leading zeros.

```
cd
cd desktop/test
j=0
convert image.png -background black -alpha background -crop 10x10% image.miff
num=`convert image.miff -format "%n\n" info: | head -n 1`
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
trans_test=`convert image.miff[$i] -alpha extract -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:mean<=0.0001?0:1]" info:`
echo "i=$i test=$trans_test"
if [ $trans_test -eq 1 ]; then
jj=`printf "%02d" $j`
convert image.miff[$i] result-$jj.png
j=$((j+1))
fi
done
rm -f image.miff
cd
```

Comment: "I am not sure why you used your commands above, but it can cropped directly without the layers composite" - that was your answer for [question by the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803478/how-to-split-an-image-with-a-grid-and-preserve-transparency-bounding-box) and I used it and it worked perfectly :)